# tweening svg attributes with greensock tweenlite (js version)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, tween, gsap

I want to use [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/#css)'s js animation platform to tween the radius of an svg circle, but it doesn't seem to be working, and I didn't see anything in the documentation about tweening attributes, only css properties. Is this possible? I essentially have this:

```
<circle r="17.451467196282987" data-rad="17.451467196282987"></circle>
```

and am trying to do this:

```
TweenLite.to($('circle'), .5, {r:25});
```

I tried doing this with jquery and it didn't work either, but I'd accept either method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it must be the way jQuery and TweenMax/Lite target the property of the element.

I have managed to get it to work using TweenLite by creating an object with a property. You can then tween the property and apply it back to the element as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var o = {r : $('circle').attr('r')};

            TweenLite.to(o, 2, {r:100, onUpdate:onUpdateHandler, onComplete:ocCompleteHandler});

            function onUpdateHandler(){
                $('circle').attr('r', o.r);
            }
            function ocCompleteHandler(){
                alert('end');
            }

    });
```

js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/g9g6M/10/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This bit just saved my day :) Note you can also use this.target instead of $('circle') in the onUpdateHandler function.

Answer (score 4):

you can animate attr values directly now

ex:
TweenLite.to("#rect", 1, {attr:{x:100, y:50, width:100, height:100}, ease:Linear.easeNone});

check out on GSAP Website
http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/